# How to make overload of operator outside class definition take precedence?

Tags: c++

I've the following operators defined:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, uint8_t b);
std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, uint32_t b);
```

When invoking the operator with an `int`, I get the error:

```
/misc.hpp:77:12: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<unsigned char>’ and ‘int’)
     buffer << first;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
./misc.hpp:62:23: note: candidate: std::vector<unsigned char>& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned char>&, uint8_t)
 std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, uint8_t b);
                       ^~~~~~~~
./misc.hpp:63:23: note: candidate: std::vector<unsigned char>& operator<<(std::vector<unsigned char>&, uint32_t)
 std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, uint32_t b);
```

Can I make the `uint8_t` version take precedence, so that I don't need a type cast, e.g., `static_cast<uint8_t>` to invoke that operator?

Comment: How do those overloads differ? Why can't there be just one?

Comment: @RustyX this is absolutely wrong. You're thinking about pre-standard C rules, not C++.

Comment: Honestly `static_cast<uint8_t>` is a really clean way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RustyX yes, there is. No it is not. And no, not really.

Answer (score 3):

You could hack it by making the second one a template:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, uint8_t b);

template<class Y>
std::vector<uint8_t> &operator<<(std::vector<uint8_t> &bytes, Y b);
```

Overload resolution will always favour a non-template function over a template one so this technique introduces an adequate hierarchy. If you don't want a plethora of `Y` types being emitted, then resort to static assertions on Y types.

Really though, a further overload to `int` is probably the sensible thing to do.

Comment: Thanks - would you elaborate with a small example of how to do static assertions on Y types? I think your idea is good...